# android.widget.ProgressBar cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-linearlayout

**GIVEN**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".InboxActivity" >

    <!-- refresh button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_refresh_inbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="refreshInbox"
        android:text="@string/refresh_inbox" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inbox_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_refresh_inbox" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/inbox_prog_bar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_inbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/inbox_container"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RESULT**:

When I run the app I get the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(930): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ProgressBar
cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**OBJECTIVE**:

Get a progress bar to show while the inbox is loading; then have the inbox content fill the linear layout.

**BACKGROUND**:

Everything has been working fine. I just thought it better to have a progress bar instead of a blank screen while the inbox is loading. Adding the progress bar caused the error. (I really want to specify the progress bar in the layout file, not programmatically).

Comment: Show us your Activity.

Comment: If you are sure that your code is right, then try cleaning project. I was having same problem and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

Refresh and Project > Clean both your projects.

This is related to some mess done when autogenerating the R references, when cleaning it will create a new one with the correct id refs.

Answer (score 1):

why would you cast to LinearLayout when it is not a base class?

```
java.lang.Object

↳ android.view.View

↳ android.widget.ProgressBar
```